# How to show an info window on tapping a marker on map?

Tags: android, google-maps

when i searched for it i found these links as solutions:

http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/04/google-map-example-in-android-with-info.html

and

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

but i found both are complicated.

I am wondering if there is any simple way to do this. Like inflating a layout and showing it as a pop up just on the marker clicked.

Right now i am using just a Toast to show info when user taps on the marker. But the main problem is I want this toast(or other layout) to appear just above the marker which is clicked, not at the default toast position.

Thank You

Comment: hey get the X and Y coordinate of touch point and display you popUp window with custom style there........

Comment: You can use `AlertDialog` it is simple and you can inflate any layout in it. But it will fill whole screen.

Comment: @VipinSahu that came to my mind 1st. But i have no idea whether i can write a code to say "this particular point of a view must come at this particular point on the scree"

Comment: @vtuhtan thats the problem. If i am showing something on the whole screen(inactive background) its a major UX issue

Comment: set an OnTouchListener on webview and find the touch point X and Y coordinate and then use hanlder to add view to map view or either display a popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, modify according to your requirement:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index)
    {
        CustomView customView=new CustomView(MyMap.this);
        absMap.removeAllViews();
        absMap.addView(customView);
        customView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.maplocation1);
        customView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        customView.removeAllViews();

          absMap.invalidate();
          customView.bringToFront();
          customView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          TextView tv2=new TextView(MyMap.this);
        //  tv2.setText(overlayItemList.get(index).getTitle());
          tv2.setWidth(170);
          tv2.setSingleLine(true);
          tv2.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
          tv2.setSingleLine(true);
          tv2.setSingleLine();

          tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
          tv2.setTextSize(14);
          tv2.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

          TextView tv1=new TextView(MyMap.this);
          tv1.setSingleLine();
          tv1.setWidth(170);
          tv1.setSingleLine(true);
          tv1.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
          tv1.setSingleLine(true);
          tv2.setText(overlayItemList.get(index).getSnippet());


          tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
          tv1.setTextSize(12);
          tv1.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
          customView.setTag(overlayItemList.get(index).getTitle());
          customView.addView(tv2, new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,10,5));
          customView.addView(tv1, new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,10,25));
          customView.setLayoutParams(new MapView.LayoutParams( 250, 100, overlayItemList.get(index).getPoint(),-125,-137, MapView.LayoutParams.MODE_MAP|MapView.LayoutParams.TOP_LEFT));
          customView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: this code will be called ontap of marker. customView is CustomView Class which extends Absolute layout, already written anywhere in your code. We just make a object of this class & use it as on the x,y positions.